# SQL- Null results not returning for select statement when executed with variable = null, but does when hardcoded

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, null

I have a stored procedure which returns a list. The variable, IS2000PolicyNo, can have a Null result from tblQuote. 
This is a simplified snippet showing just the variables causing the problems.

```css
@IS2000PolicyNo int,

   IF @IS2000PolicyNo = -1 
SET @IS2000PolicyNo = NULL 
 
   BEGIN TRY
SELECT
 List= replace( (  SELECT top 500 
                        cast(ISNULL(T.IS2000PolicyNo,'') as varchar)  + ';'
  FROM
 (SELECT DISTINCT
      Q.IS2000PolicyNo
   FROM
 dbo.tblQuote Q
  WHERE
  cast(isnull(Q.IS2000PolicyNo,'')as varchar)  LIKE '%'+ CAST(ISNULL(@IS2000PolicyNo,'')as varchar) + '%' )
```

I execute the procedure passing -1, the IF statement converts it to null, which should return all the records, but it skips the records with null values for IS2000PolicyNo. 
When I hard code into the Where statement to have @IS2000PolicyNo equal to null, it returns all the records including the nulls.

```css
WHERE
  cast(isnull(Q.IS2000PolicyNo,'')as varchar)  LIKE '%'+ CAST(ISNULL(null,'')as varchar + '%')
```

I have also tried just setting `@IS2000PolicyNo = null` instead of the If statement, and it does not return the null values.

I have stepped through the code and it correctly converts the fields to a blank in the If statements.

Thanks!

Comment: Looks like SQL Server? Please tag product used (so you get the best attention!)

Comment: Can you trim your question to only problem area. For NULL we use IS NULL, I am not sure if you are using it. Just mentioning.

Comment: "I have hard-coded 'null' into the where statement"  Wait, do you mean you used `'%'+ CAST(ISNULL(NULL,'')as varchar) + '%'` or you used `'%'+ CAST(ISNULL('NULL','')as varchar) + '%'`?

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that the problem is this line:

```
cast(isnull(Q.IS2000PolicyNo,'')as varchar) LIKE '%' + CAST(ISNULL(@IS2000PolicyNo,'')as varchar) + '%'
```

This is highly suspicious:

- Why are the values stored as ints but compared as strings?
- Why doesn't `varchar()` have a length?  (Very dangerous practice, but not the problem here.)
- What do you expect to happen when you pass in `-1`, which is *not* `NULL`?

One possibility is just to do the comparisons as `ints`.  It is a bit difficult to follow the logic but this might be sufficient:

```
((Q.IS2000PolicyNo = @IS2000PolicyNo) or coalesce(@IS2000PolicyNo, -1) = -1))
```

Or perhaps:

```
((Q.IS2000PolicyNo = '%' + cast(@IS2000PolicyNo as varchar(255)) + '%') or
 (coalesce(@IS2000PolicyNo, -1) = -1))
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, ISNULL converts output to the same datatype as the input. Since your parameter is an INT, the return type is an INT. See it in action as it returns 0:

```
declare @foo as int;
set @foo = null;
select ISNULL(@foo,'');
```

To resolve, you should CAST that parameter to a VARCHAR inside your ISNULL check, not outside of it.

Or, use the ANSI standard COALESCE instead of ISNULL and you won't have this issue. [A good explanation is here](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/coalesce-vs-isnull), specifically:

> COALESCE and ISNULL differ in how they determine the data type of the
>   resulting expression.
>
> The data type of a COALESCE expression is the data type of the input
>   argument with the highest data type precedence. If all inputs are the
>   untyped NULL literal, you get an error.
>
> The data type of an ISNULL expression is the data type of the first
>   input. If the first input is an untyped NULL literal, the data type of
>   the result is the type of the second input. If both inputs are the
>   untyped literal, the type of the output is INT.

My final thought is, why is the parameter an INT if you're re-casting it into a VARCHAR throughout your queries? You can resolve the problem and possibly get better speed by changing the parameter's data type to a VARCHAR.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone! I've changed it so it used varchar the whole way through. That was part of the problem, then I also had to use Nz(policyno,"") so it would display on the front end.